# Programmatically Mapping AWS Resource Types to AWS Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x, aws-security-hub

I would like to map AWS Resource Types to AWS Services programmatically when fetching AWS SecurityHub findings. For example, if an AWS SecurityHub finding indicates the affected resource with `AwsS3Bucket`, I would like to convert that to AWS S3 as this is the corresponding AWS Service. Does the AWS APIs offer such a conversion, I am working with Java.

Answer (score 1):

There's no API for an automatic conversion. However, you can get all available resource types from the JSON document avaliable at [AWS Security Finding Format (ASFF) documentation](https://go.aws/3OoDIpV). All types can be found in `Resources.Details` (see JSON snippet below).

With this you can create a converter with an in-memory lookup list or a lookup table in DynamoDB to retrieve the respective service.

```json
"Findings": [ 
    {
        ...
        "Resources": [{
            ...
            "Details": {
                "AwsAmazonMQBroker": { ... },
                "AwsApiGatewayRestApi": { ... },
                ...
            }
        }]
    }
]
```